# Converting C Macro to VHDL

Tags: c, vhdl

I'm fairly new to VHDL and trying to convert two given C macros to be executed as a single instruction on my FPGA. The macros are:

```
#define m_in_bits(buf, num) (buf) >> (24 - (num)) // buf is uint32_t
#define m_ext_bits(buf, i) ((buf) < (1<<((i)-1)) ? (buf) + (((-1)<<(i)) + 1) : (buf))
```

And the C code that uses the macros is:

```
m_ext_bits(m_in_bits(buffer, size), size);
```

I'm having issues with getting `m_ext_bits` to properly compile. Here's my VHDL:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity myEntity is
port(
  signal buffer: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal result: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end entity myEntity;

architecture myArch of myEntity  is
  signal size : signed (3 downto 0);
begin

size <= signed(buffer(27 downto 24));

result(15 downto 0) <= std_logic_vector(signed(buffer(23 downto 0)) srl (24 - to_integer(size))
                     + signed((-1 sll to_integer(size)) + 1)); -- the offending line

end architecture myArch ;
```

The long line beginning with `result(15 downto 0) <=` actually compiles without error (that implements the `m_in_bits` macro). However, when I add the following line, beginning with the `+`, errors occur. I tried playing around with casting the `std_logic_vector` and `signed` types and the errors change.

> type of expression is ambiguous - "SIGNED" or "UNSIGNED" are two possible matches...
>   can't determine definition of operator ""sll"" -- found 0 possible definitions...
>   illegal SIGNED in expression...

I think it's a matter of proper casting and using the correct types to fulfill the required operations.

Comment: This should be migrated to http://electronics.stackexchange.com. You'll find a lot more VHDL experts there.

Comment: @DoxyLover - notice the tag [tag:vhdl]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `buffer` is a reserved VHDL word, so change that; using `argbuf` below.

The expression `-1 sll to_integer(size)` is not defined in VHDL, since the
integer value `-1` is a numerical expression only with no bit representation
specified by VHDL, so shifting is not possible.  Neither are operations like
bitwise and, or, etc. on integers.  A -1 representation in 24-bit `signed` type can be created as:

```
to_signed(-1, 24)
```

There is a length issue with the assign, since 16-bit signal (`result(15 downto
0)`) is assigned with 24-bit value (based on right side `argbuf(23 downto 0)`).

The `srl` should then compile when the above is addressed.

Code as:

```
result(15 downto 0) <= std_logic_vector(resize((signed(argbuf(23 downto 0)) srl (24 - to_integer(size)))
                                               + signed((to_signed(-1, 24) sll to_integer(size)) + 1), 16));
```

However, the VHDL shift operators, e.g. `srl`, may give unexpected results, as
described in this page ["Arithmetic and logical shifts and rotates are done with
functions in VHDL, not
operators"](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/bit-shifts-in-vhdl.html),
so you may consider using the shift functions defined in numeric_std instead,
e.g. `shift_right`, as a general coding style.  Code with functions as:

```
result(15 downto 0) <= std_logic_vector(resize(shift_right(signed(argbuf(23 downto 0)), 24 - to_integer(size))
                                               + signed(shift_left(to_signed(-1, 24), to_integer(size)) + 1), 16));
```

Comment: Whoops, I shortened variable names for the question and ended up with `buffer` but thanks for the hint. I thought of the length issue with `result` but the right shift, in practice, ensures that the value fits within 16 bits (either that or it's fine to be cut off). So, how can I create the value that is equivalent to left shifting `-1`?

Comment: For -1 shifting, convert to signed and shift.  For length adjust, do it explicitly using `resize`.  See code added to answer above.